# Proving $x$ is a given quotient of logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I'm practicing some questions on logarithms at the moment in order that I'm up to speed with the problem solving aspect before I embark on my PHD in chemical engineering at Boston college next year.

I've been studying the laws of logarithms and what I am to do when it is necessary to add and subtract logs. So for example, for the first part of the question that is causing me trouble, I would utilize the first law of logarithms.

My issue comes with the "Prove part", and ascertaining a value for $x$ when it is already involved in the first part of the question.

I know I'll most likely to be shut down for lack of evidence and research for this, but I would like to know what the most logical first step would be and which rule I need to follow. It doesn't follow on from the other questions I've been solving and so I can't problem solve it as easily as I can the rest.

Here is my question:

If $4^x\cdot 5^{3x+1}=10^{2x+1}$, prove that $x=\dfrac{\log(2)}{\log(5)}$.

Thanks, not a problem if I get shut down, I know this isn't in the spirit of the website and would normally never ask a question in such a manner.

Comment: For the sake of typesetting, it is recommended to use MathJax and $\LaTeX$, or at the very least use parenthesis so that there is no confusion as to what is meant to go where.  Visit [this page for information](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics here.  Is the equation meant to be $4^x 5^{3x+1} = 10^{2x+1}$?  Is it meant to be $4^{x5^{3x}+1}=10^{2x}+1$ is it meant to be $4^x5^3x+1 = 10^2x+1$ or something else entirely?

Comment: Seems like your question is perfectly in line with the spirit of the website.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I must learnt the code as it'll prove invaluable to me. 

The equation is the first you mentioned, with everything being a power apart from the 4, 5 and 10.

Thanks, M47145. I'm sat here with an inordinate amount of maths textbooks open trying to get my head around this one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$4^x\cdot 5^{3x+1} = 10^{2x+1}$$

$~~$Let us begin by moving everything to one side by dividing both sides by $10^{2x+1}$

$$\dfrac{4^x\cdot 5^{3x+1}}{10^{2x+1}} = 1$$

$~~$Let us separate the denominator using the fact that $10=2\cdot 5$

$$\dfrac{4^x\cdot 5^{3x+1}}{(2\cdot 5)^{2x+1}} = 1$$

$~~$Now, $(ab)^c = a^c\cdot b^c$

$$\dfrac{4^x\cdot 5^{3x+1}}{2^{2x+1}\cdot 5^{2x+1}} = 1$$

$~~$Let us factor out a factor of two from the denominator using $a^{b+c} = a^b\cdot a^c$

$$\dfrac{4^x\cdot 5^{3x+1}}{2^{2x}\cdot 2\cdot 5^{2x+1}}=1$$

$~~$Now, using $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ simplify $2^{2x}$ in terms of a power of four

$$\dfrac{4^x\cdot 5^{3x+1}}{4^x\cdot 2\cdot 5^{2x+1}}=1$$

$~~$Cancel like terms and use $\frac{a^b}{a^c} = a^{b-c}$

$$\frac{5^x}{2}=1$$

$~~$Multiply both sides by two

$$5^x=2$$

$~~$Take the logarithm of each side

$$\log(5^x)=\log(2)$$

$~~$Use the property of logarithms that $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$

$$x\log(5)=\log(2)$$

$~~$Divide each side by $\log(5)$ to arrive at the desired result

$$x=\frac{\log(2)}{\log(5)}$$

Comment: It is not recommended to use [quotes for highlighting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23015/is-using-blockquote-for-highlighting-problematic).

Comment: @IanMiller given the amount of text inbetween each step, I find it harder to quickly read without, but have edited it according to your suggestion.  Hopefully this is a fine compromise.

Comment: I replaced your single \$ equations with double \$\$ equations to make it look more like your original.

Comment: JMoravitz, thank you for this excellent breakdown. It was invaluable to my learning, honestly. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

**Alternative Solution:**

Recall the laws of logarithms:

1. $\log a^b = b \log a$.
2. $\log ab = \log a + \log b$
3. $\log \frac{a}{b} = \log a - \log b$

By taking the logarithm on both sides of your equation and applying rule (1), you will get:
$$
x \log 4 + (3x + 1) \log 5 = (2x + 1) \log (10)
$$
which can be simplified to
$$
(\log 4 + 3 \log 5 – 2 \log 10) x = \log(10) - \log(5)
$$

Using the mentioned rules, we get
$$
\log\left(\frac{4 \times 5^3}{10^2}\right) x = \log\left(\frac{10}{5}\right)
$$
which establish your result.

Comment: Thank you FALAM for helping me to understand this utlizing the laws of logarithms, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
4^x \cdot 5^{3x+1}
    & = 2^{2x} \cdot 5^{3x+1} \\
    & = 2^{2x} \cdot 5^{2x} \cdot 5^{x+1} \\
    & = 10^{2x} \cdot 5^{x+1}
\end{align}

If $10^{2x} \cdot 5^{x+1} = 10^{2x+1}$ (the hypothesis of the problem), then

$$
5^{x+1} = 10
$$
$$
5^x \cdot 5^1 = 10
$$
$$
5^x = 2
$$

which gives us, by definition,

$$
x = \log_5 2
$$

which can be rewritten, using $\log_b x = \frac{\log x}{\log b}$, as

$$
x = \frac{\log 2}{\log 5}
$$

Comment: Thanks for this version Brian, it was very helpful to me.